# CSS: Add element to middle of float

Tags: html, css

I want to add an element to middle to the panel. I'm using `float: right` and `float:left` to divide the panel. I'm not using bootstrap here.

i used `clear: both;` and `margin: 0 auto;` styles and it's not working for me. Is there any possible way to do that? I have attached a sample image that what i want. [image]

Any help highly appreciate.
Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: `clear: both;` will do the opposite of what you want

Comment: @MarkPerera Thanks for your help. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this this might help you.

you can simply use ***width 1/3*** and ***float left*** to make it

and ***text-align: center*** is to center text

**Basic structure**

```css
.col{
width: 33.33%;
text-align: center;

}

.left{
  float: left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col left">
something
</div>
<div class="col left">
something is here!!
</div>
<div class="col left">
something
</div>
```

**Your design**

```css
.col{
width: 32%;
height: 300px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: .5%;
margin-right: .5%;

}

.left{
  float: left;
  }

.black{
background-color: black;
color: white;
}

.red{
background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="col left black">
something
</div>
<div class="col left red">
something is here!!
</div>
<div class="col left black">
something
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called `float:center` in css you just have to use float left or right and it is very important that you make the html code in tree structure.

Here is the working [codepen](http://codepen.io/rohitbind/pen/xOjWdK). Code is given below.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col20 black">
                  Float : left.
            </div>
            <div class="col60 red">
                  Added Something here.
            </div>
            <div class="col20 black">
                  Float : Right.
            </div>
      </div>
</div>



*{
      box-sizing : border-box;
}
.container{
      width:800px;
      margin:0 auto;
}
.row{
      width:100%;
      text-align: center;
}
.row:after{
      clear:both;
      content:"";
      display:block;
}
.row:before{
      clear:both;
      content:"";
      display:block;
}
.col20{
      width:20%;
      float:left;
      height:200px;
}
.col60{
      width:60%;
      float:left;
      height:200px;
}
.black{
      background:#000;
      color:#fff;
}
.red{
      background:red;
      Color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is if these are taking up the full width and height of the parent you could just use Flexbox layout:

`.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.parent > * {
    flex: 1 1 auto; /* Or you can specify specific widths. I would suggest one being 1 1 auto though. */
}`

`<div class="parent">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></></div>
    <div class="right"></></div>
</div>`